# Vue3 onMounted not working on page refresh

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a function that checks if the text is truncated and if so displays a button to expand the hidden text.

I've setup a code demo with full detail, I dont have any errors but the logic does not seem to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

SCRIPT:

```
const information = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)

onMounted(() => {
  // initialize 'information' ref status
  informationRefStatus()
})

function informationRefStatus() {
  if (information.value) {
    const element = information.value
    return isTextTruncated.value = element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight
  }
}
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<div>
  <div ref="information" :class="isExpanded ? 'truncate' : ''">
    {{ data?.information }}
  </div>
  <span
    v-if="isTextTruncated"
    @click="isExpanded = !isExpanded"
  >
    {{ toggleCtaLabel }}
  </span>
</div>
```

[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/upbeat-butterfly-zpphj7?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A24%2C49)

Comment: You're using TypeScript features but haven't set the component to allow TypeScript which is causing `information.value` to be undefined (the `if` statement is then failing).  Make sure to enable TypeScript support with `<script lang="ts">`

Comment: @yoduh It can be debugged to information === 0, this gives some clue what's going on.

Comment: Ah thank you, in my codebase I do actually have <script lang="ts">. Is every thing else correct?

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks the important part:

```
<script>
...
const information = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
```

`script` tag makes `ref < HTMLElement | null > null` to be parsed as JavaScript expression, which is incidentally valid and results in `information` not being a Vue ref without syntax errors.

It should be:

```
<script lang="ts">
...
```